# Joining two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
RIC | base
AAPL| AA
IBM |
AMD |
```

and another table with same fields but different values:

```
RIC | base
AAPL | AA
IBM | 
AMD | AM
```

I would like to join the two tables to get this resultant table:

```
RIC | base
AAPL | AA
IBM | 
AMD | AM
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you notice that your desired result is the same as your second dataframe?

I think you meant something like this:

Consider the two dataframes `d1` and `d2`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(RIC=['AAPL', 'IBM', 'AMD'], base=['AA', None, None]))
d2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(RIC=['AAPL', 'IBM', 'AMD'], base=['aa', 'IB', 'AM']))

print(d1)
print()
print(d2)

    RIC  base
0  AAPL    AA
1   IBM  None
2   AMD  None

    RIC base
0  AAPL   aa
1   IBM   IB
2   AMD   AM
```

We'll use `set_index` and `combine_first`

```
d1.set_index('RIC').combine_first(d2.set_index('RIC')).reset_index()

    RIC base
0  AAPL   AA
1   IBM   IB
2   AMD   AM
```

This approach takes the values from the first dataframe when it exists.  Otherwise, it takes the value from the second dataframe.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of combine_first. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you try : pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)